# What does $t\in [0, N )$ mean?

Tags: notation

I know it means that t is an element in the range from 0 to all natural numbers (I think) but what do the `[` and `)` represent?

Comment: It means that $0\leq t<N$ or that $t$ is bigger or equal to $0$ and less than $N$

Comment: Awesome, thanks

Comment: $[A,B)$ is the standard notation for the set $\{x\in \Bbb R: A\leq x<B\}.$... And  $[A,\infty)$ means $\{x\in \Bbb R: A\leq x\}$.